# Upgrade Issue in Installshield 2008 Premier Edition

Tags: localization, internationalization, upgrade, installshield, multilingual

I am facing problem while upgrading an Higher version over Lower version. I have implemented multilingual support; Assume that older version being installed in French while doing upgrade it is coming in English which is my Operating System language; in fact it should show in French.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you configured the installation to prompt for the users language, rather than detecting the OS locale? Simply go to the Releases view, find your release and ensure that the "Languages Dialog" is set to yes.

Since the installed language of the app is different to the OS language, you'll need to prompt the user. You can't detect a previously installed language that early in InstallShield as far as I know.

Comment: Yes i have enabled the "Languages Dialog". All i want to know; is there any option or way to change the display language while doing Upgrade..

Comment: Have you tried opening a support incident with InstallShield or asking on their forums?

Comment: hi,
at last i found that it is not possible in Installshield 2008 Premier edition; in Installshield forum the release notes of Installshield it is a known Issue and it is fixed in Installshield 2009 version
Thanks for the help.. :)